# Elasticsearch field limit problems

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, opensearch

What happens if i have a higher no of fields in elastic i know that the indexing and search latency increases, Ram and cache usage increases but can someone explain in depth what happens internally,
what kind of data/ data structure is stored in Ram
Why does CPU increase, does GC increase as well

From what i gathered is that this information is in the cluster state which needs to be propagated to every node so the larger it gets more expensive it becomes but can someone throw more details into all this

Answer (score 0):

In Elasticsearch and OpenSearch, an increase in the *quantity* of data — or number of fields — has an impact on every node metric. The [Field Data Cache Allocation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/modules-fielddata.html)** defines what quantity of data is stored by the node(s) in memory/RAM. This is typically set to 20% within Amazon OpenSearch Service.

In practice, this means that 20% of RAM is consumed by a cache of your documents, enabling nodes to respond to queries and GET requests faster.

Regarding multiple nodes and propagation, *data nodes* handle indexing and queries, however, if your cluster has no dedicated master nodes, they are also responsible for propagating data across the cluster — dependent on the quantity of data, this can be a computationally-intensive task. This is likely why you're seeing an increase in CPU utilization.

If the instance health/metrics is becoming a problem, adding [dedicated master nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-dedicatedmasternodes.html) will definitely reduce the compute (CPU) strain on the data nodes. You may also consider reducing the field data cache allocation, although, this will impact performance. AWS [recommend 40% for larger indices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/createupdatedomains.html#createdomain-configure-advanced-options).

Ultimately, Elastic/OpenSearch is a complex, albeit effective system for data storage and search. There is a large overhead involved with orchestrating the cluster, replication of shards, etc. If it's within your price point, you may want to consider [AWS OpenSearch Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/serverless.html) which does not require the same level of provisioning/monitoring as with conventional clusters.

*** documentation for Elasticsearch 7.10.2*